# Unable to create a PodPreset on EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-eks

Environment:
AWS managed Kubernetes cluster (EKS)

Action:
Create a PodPreset object by applying the following:

```
apiVersion: settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: PodPreset
meta data:
  name: sample
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: microservice
    env:
      - name: test_env
        value: "6379"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: shared
        mountPath: /usr/shared
    volumes:
      - name: shared
        emptyDir: {}
```

Observation:

```
unable to recognize "podpreset.yaml": no matches for kind "PodPreset" in version "settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

Comment: Of note: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that the API version `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1` is not supported by default by EKS.
I'm using EKS as well, I just run this commands to check it out:

```
$ kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

The I run

```
curl localhost:8001/apis
```

And clearly in my case `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1` was not supported. I recommend running the same checks.
Also checking [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/) it's mentioned that

> You should have enabled the API type settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpreset

I don't know how can the `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1` can be enabled in EKS.

Answer (score 0):

EKS does not enable any k8s Alpha feature and as of today, PodPreset is a k8s Alpha feature. So if you want to achieve something like above, you have will have to create a Mutating Admission webhook which is supported by EKS now. But it is not sure simple use cases, PodPreset can handle most of the simple use cases hopefully it will enter Beta Phase soon.

Answer (score 0):

As of 03.11.2020 there is still an [open GitHub](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/151) request for this.